# Data of backing bean in View Scope shared across multiple users

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope

One of my JSF backing bean is in View Scope (since there is data table which requires pagination).

The problem is that, when two users access this backing bean at the same time, the results in data table are getting overlapped.

Comment: Are you saying that this doesn't happen when webapp is not deployed in a clustered environment?

Comment: Not necessarily. Even in non clustered environment it behaves the same way.

Comment: Apparently it's either actually not view scoped or your code is not threadsafe. Hard to tell without a MCVE.

Comment: is there anything I need to do other than to annotate backing with @ViewScoped?

Comment: Same problem , did you find an answer?